# El login no carga el acceso en PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo un registor de usuarios y login en PHP, pero al momento de añadir un usuario e iniciar sesión la página solo recarga sin dejarme ver el contenido principal. Anexo el código:

Gracias por la ayuda, de antemano.

---

PHP DEL LOGIN

```
<?php session_start();
    
    // Comprobamos si ya tiene una sesion
    # Si ya tiene una sesion redirigimos al contenido, para que no pueda acceder al formulario
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }
    
    // Comprobamos si ya han sido enviado los datos
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password = hash('sha512', $password);
    
        // Nos conectamos a la base de datos
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fqc', 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM admins WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :password');
        $statement->execute(array(
                ':usuario' => $usuario,
                ':password' => $password
            ));
    
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();
        if ($resultado !== false) {
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $errores = '<li>Datos incorrectos</li>';
        }
    }
    
    require 'views/login.view.php';
    
    ?>
```

---

PHP DEL REGISTRO

```
<?php session_start();

// Comprobamos si ya tiene una sesion
# Si ya tiene una sesion redirigimos al contenido, para que no pueda volver a registrar un usuario.
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

// Comprobamos si ya han sido enviado los datos
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Validamos que los datos hayan sido rellenados
    $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];



    $errores = '';

    // Comprobamos que ninguno de los campos este vacio.
    if (empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2)) {
        $errores = '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
    } else {

        // Comprobamos que el usuario no exista ya.
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fqc', 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM admins WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));

        // El metodo fetch nos va a devolver el resultado o false en caso de que no haya resultado.
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();

        // Si resultado es diferente a false entonces significa que ya existe el usuario.
        if ($resultado != false) {
            $errores .= '<li>El nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
        }

        // Hasheamos la contraseña para protegerla un poco.
        # La seguridad es un tema muy complejo, aqui solo estamos haciendo un hash de la contraseña,
        # pero esto no asegura por completo la informacion encriptada.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password);
        $password2 = hash('sha512', $password2);

        // Comprobamos que las contraseñas sean iguales.
        if ($password != $password2) {
            $errores.= '<li>Las contraseñas no son iguales</li>';
        }
    }

    // Comprobamos si hay errores, sino entonces agregamos el usuario y redirigimos.
    if ($errores == '') {
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO admins (id, usuario, pass) VALUES (null, :usuario, :pass)');
        $statement->execute(array(
                ':usuario' => $usuario,
                ':pass' => $password
            ));

        // Despues de registrar al usuario redirigimos para que inicie sesion.
        header('Location: login.php');
    }


}

require 'views/registrate.view.php';
?>
```

Comment: Hola Francisco, cuando pones el código en formato de imagen en lugar de texto, eso hace que muchos usuarios tengan dificultad para verlo y ejecutarlo. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadir el código en modo texto. También deberías añadir el error que recibes (no sólo el que muestras por pantalla, también el mensaje de la consulta). Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta. A qué te refieres con "sin ver el contenido principal"? Si todo sale bien, parece que rediriges a un index.php, pero no es evidente cuál es el problema :)

Answer (score 0):

si no te muestra nada es posible que te esté mostrando un error y algunos navegadores no tienen activa y/o ocultan los mensajes con php. En el index o la página que quede en blanco pon esta función en la primeras lineas.

```
<?php
// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(-1);
 
 
// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 
// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
```